# Tracing LoadLibrary or LdrLoadDll

Tags: winapi, dll

I need to get the directory search path followed while loading a DLL. So I need to trace either the `LoadLibrary` or `LdrLoadDll` function call to get the path followed from its arguments. Is there any tool to trace it or any tool to obtain the directory search order followed while loading a DLL?

Comment: This should be tagged **win32** and/or **win32api**

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon.  You'll see the app searching for the DLL.  Best done by not allowing it to find the DLL so you'll see the order in which it searches the directories.  This is well documented btw.

Comment: Documented in? I downloaded the ProcMon but i couldnt explore the help file

Comment: Well, best just to use the documentation in my view. It's here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your debugger should be able to tell you everything you need quite easily. It knows the full path to any loaded modules, as well as the current directory. That is enough to answer anything you need to know about DLL search paths.

Answer (score 5):

Use [APIMonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and trace the `LdrLoadDll` function